# Why table "Type" parameter in SQL Server 2008 is made READONLY

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have searched but I did not found simple understandable answer. My question is: why is the table "Type" parameter in SQL Server 2008 made READONLY while using in stored procedure?

Comment: Ask the SQL Server design team .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine it would be to avoid unintended side effects.  If you pass in a table as an **INPUT** parameter, you would not expect it to be changed.  The same could be said of any input parameter - if you pass in an `@ID` of 12 and after you run the stored procedure the `@ID` is suddenly set to 14, this could cause lots of hard to debug issues.

You can still make changes to inputted table parameters but you need to make a separate **OUTPUT** parameter for it so that the changes are explicit.